# Pattern matching for a zip file using regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

The below zip file needs to be checked with the pattern it is located or not in a directory. How can i match the pattern with RegEx?

Zip File:

```
TestReport-20140311_18121024-BWSI MGMT-74482677-00f0-49ea-9330-f60738da4bc0.zip
```

Pattern to match:

```
TestReport-{YYYYMMDD_HHmmssff}-[BWSI MGMT]-[UniqueId].zip
```

Here,

UniqueId is `74482677-00f0-49ea-9330-f60738da4bc0`

Comment: to verify against what?

Comment: need to check the zip file is there or not as per the pattern given above in the  directory

Comment: For once, I'd say this would be better done with `Split` and `x.Parse` than with a regex.

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Comment: How expansive does your RegEx need to be? For example, will MachineName(SI) be matched against a value or will it have to be matched against a pattern as well? If you don't know MachineName(SI) at runtime, what are the rules for how MachineName(SI) can be formatted? I'm assuming that you will be running the RegEx over a list of filenames and only returning the matching results.

Comment: updated the question with the pattern type

Comment: @sukumar are any of the answers useful to you or do you need something else?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to be lazy about this, you can just do it with a one-line regular expression:

```
Regex rx("TestReport-(?<year>\d{4})(?<month>\d{2})(?<day>\d{2})_(?<hours>\d{2})(?<minutes>\d{2})(?<seconds>\d{2})(?<fractions>\d{2})-(?<machine>.*?)-(?<guid>[a-f\d]{8}-[a-f\d]{4}-[a-f\d]{4}-[a-f\d]{4}-[a-f\d]{12}).zip", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

However, you could as well just split the name at given intervalls, assuming the names are sure to be constant/in that format.

Answer (score 0):

This regex will do it:

```
(?i)TestReport-\d{8}_\d{8}-[a-z\s]+?-[a-f\d]{8}-(?:[a-f\d]{4}-){3}[a-f\d]{12}.zip
```

Note that it doesn't check that the date value is actually a valid date, just that it has the digits in the correct positions.

- `(?i)` turns off case sensitivity.
- `\d{8}_\d{8}` matches date.
- `[a-z\s]+?` matches `BWSI MGMT`. I wasn't sure if this would always be this string. If it is, then you could replace with `BWSI\sMGMT`.
- `-[a-f\d]{8}-(?:[a-f\d]{4}-){3}[a-f\d]{12}` matches the unique ID. `(?:)` is a non-capturing group.